# I am pretty sure I have a memory leak in a recursive function but I don't know how to fix it

Tags: c, recursion, memory-leaks, malloc

I am running a search function on a binary tree that will return a binary tree with the root of the returned tree being the search query so for example if I had:

100 as the root,

50 and 150 as its children,

20 and 70 and 50's children ----&---- 120 and 170 as 150's children

if I put 50 as the key to my search function it would return a binary tree with 50 as the root and 20 and 70 as its children. This is all done with pointers. My problem is that I am malloc'ing a new BST(binary search tree) struct every recursive call and not freeing it, so I am almost positive I am having a memory leak, but I don't know how to fix it without free'ing the memory before it is used. Below is my function.

```
typedef struct node { 
    int key; 
    struct node *left, *right; 
} Node; 

typedef struct binarySearchTree {
    Node* top;
} BST;

BST *search(BST* bst, int key) {
    // Base Cases: root is null or key is present at root 
    if (bst->top == NULL || bst->top->key == key) {
        return bst;
    }

    // Key is greater than root's key 
    if (bst->top->key < key) {
        BST *temp = malloc(sizeof(BST));
        temp->top = bst->top->right;
        return search(temp, key); 
    }

    // Key is smaller than root's key 
    BST *temp = malloc(sizeof(BST));
    temp->top = bst->top->left;
    return search(temp, key); 
}
```

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you ever want to `malloc` in a search function? It is not supposed to create any new data.

Comment: Just use `return search(bst->top->right, key)` and the same for left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need to be allocating memory for a search function.  It seems the problem is that you're passing around a `BST` object when you should be passing around a `Node` object.

```
Node* search(Node* node, int key){ 
    if (node== NULL) return NULL;

    if (node->key < key) {
        return search(node->left, key); 
    } else if (node->key > key){
        return search(node->right, key); 
    } else {
        return node;
    }
}
```

Now the function will return the node that contains the key, or `NULL` if it wasn't found.

Comment: Yes, this is true, but a requirement is that the search function can receive a BST as input, would it be best to use that search function within another function whose only purpose is to take in a BST and then pass its root to the search function you recommended?

Comment: @AdamMenker Yes, you would create a wrapper function that takes a `BST` and passes the root node to the recursive search function.